# Web Page Reading Without Affecting Visitor Count

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, html, httpwebresponse

I'm writing a program that is reading webpage contents whith C# Windows Forms. I'm using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx) thats ok no problem with reading any content. But the pages visitor counter is affected by that and it's rising. I don't want to rise the visitor counter. I use `UserAgent` info `"Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)"` but it doesn't solve my problem. How do I solve this problem whitout affecting visitor counter the web page. I'm sory my little english, please help me.

My codes is this:

```
HttpWebRequest wReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
wReq.Method = "GET"; // Alredy use a POST
wReq.MediaType = "HTTP/1.1";
wReq.ContentType = "text/xml";
wReq.Referer = "http://googlebot.com/"; // Already use site name
wReq.UserAgent = "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)";
wReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
wReq.Timeout = 10000;
WebResponse wRes = wReq.GetResponse();
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9");
StreamReader sRed = new StreamReader(wRes.GetResponseStream(), enc);
return sRed.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you'll be able to do this.  If you are using the Google user agent and it still goes up, then when the real Google accesses the page it will probably go up as well.  It is really the site's problem for not filtering out robots in their hit counter.

Comment: I'm trying this code a big and famous dealing site. Does your mind another solution my friend.

Comment: No, the other site will always see your request so it is up to them whether or not to increment the counter.